# Set ringtone in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

How can an application set a ringtone on iPhone?

Comment: I think there are apps in the appstore that do this. 1. http://itunes.apple.com/se/app/best-ringtone-maker/id389350868?mt=8 2. http://itunes.apple.com/se/app/ringtone-designer-pro/id383819300?mt=8 3. http://itunes.apple.com/se/app/music-ringtone-maker/id382657247?mt=8 4. http://itunes.apple.com/se/app/ringtonemaker-pro/id390777480?mt=8 5. http://itunes.apple.com/se/app/custom-ringtone-maker/id389082673?mt=8 How they do it, I don't know. But I guess it should be possible.

Comment: These applications usually just create and convert audio to .m4r file and store it in places they have access to. They do not access the iPhone's ringtone directory. You still need a computer with iTunes to download and sync the ringtone with your iPhone.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This feature is not supported in the API currently since it could be used to set the ringtone to something that the user did not intend to set it to. If you'd like to see it added, best thing to do is submit a feature request to Apple.