# change ringer in iPhone via code

Tags: iphone

I couldn't find it in the documentation, so I'd ask: is there a way to get/set the ringtone for a specific user in the address book (programatically, of course)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829369/set-ringtone-in-iphone-sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't an official API to do that. Submiting a [feature request](https://bugreport.apple.com) is all you can do.