# Can we set Ringtone using iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone

in my app i have some audio files which i am playing, can set those audio files as ringtones.

Thank You

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set ringtone in iPhone SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829369/set-ringtone-in-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, No. It would bad business for Apple, who selling ringtones through iTunes.