# Any way to change iphone ringtone programmactically?

Tags: iphone

HI All,

I need to change the iphone ringtone and wallpaper programmatic by my application .Is there any API in iphone os 4 or in lower version by whcich we can change the iphone ringtone by our code.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set ringtone in iPhone SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829369/set-ringtone-in-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Apple does not want apps changing user settings for basic phone functionality.