# Making ringtone of music files on Iphone

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to edit music files stored on iphone in app and create ringtone from them?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: as an iPhone app?  It would not be approved for the app store... does that derail your idea?

Comment: ok. Can i edit music files local to my app? I mean are there any api's for editing audio or converting?

Comment: Are you asking about an app that you wrote?  There are audio api functions available in the SDK.  Maybe if your question was clearer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any way to change iphone ringtone programmactically ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536573/any-way-to-change-iphone-ringtone-programmactically)

Comment: @Brad 

I dont want to change ringtones. I want to create ringtones.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to extract the music from an existing iPhone app, and then turn that music from the app into a ring tone?

The short answer is no, not if you keep your iDevice up to date and within apple's licensed operating paradigm.

The longer answer is maybe.  If you jailbreak the device, you may be able to hack access to the application and extract the desired data.

If I don't understand correctly, and you're just looking to change any old mp3 into an iPhone ringtone, try googling for iPhone ringtone hacks. Of course your mileage may vary but google is again your friend.

Sorry to not provide any code.  This question didn't seem to warrant it.

Comment: My appologies for not providing links.  Apparently my method of posting URLs was not well liked by the submission box.

Answer (score 1):

No, for a number of reasons. The SDK doesn't give you access to the actual file data from the music library (just an object that will play music back for you), and while you can probably export an M4A file, with an "m4r" extension that iTunes will recognize as a ringtone, you'll have to get the user to take the file off their device and import it into iTunes manually for it to be usable as an actual ringtone on their phone.

Comment: there's already an application that does this, but it will copy the song to it's working path, cut it in 40 seconds and then prompt the user to sync it with iTunes. Useless.