# setting ringtone programmatically in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set ringtone in iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829369/set-ringtone-in-iphone-sdk)

How to set ringtone programmatically in iPhone..are there any ways other than jailbreak?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not without jailbreaking, nope.