# How to download a ringtone from internet to iphone by using an application?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I want to download a ringtone from internet to my iphone by using an application, which i want to create. And also i want to add it to my ringtones. So, how can i do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set ringtone in iPhone SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829369/set-ringtone-in-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS apps are not allowed to write files outside their sandbox. Only jailbroken iPhones can write to folder for ringtones which is /Library/Ringtones.