# MonoTouch Setting Ringtone possible?

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, ringtone

I have searched through the samples and answers available but I haven't found a way to set a sound file as a ringtone. Is that option blocked on iPhone with MonoTouch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general Apple does not allow application to make global changes in devices. So **yes** it's restricted but **no** it's not a MonoTouch related restriction.

For this specific case see: [Set ringtone in iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829369/set-ringtone-in-iphone-sdk)

Comment: Is there a way I can download via the application and then using the iPhone only set the new file as a ringtone?

Comment: I don't think so. Generally applications are isolated from each other and from the OS itself.