# Access sound settings in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, settings, audio, ringtone

In one of my app i wanted to access the sound settings and need to do some modification like increase the volume, change the tune . does apple allow these kind of the app ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, it is not possible to do so in current iOS SDK .

There is no public API since iOS 5.1 to access Settings App. However, you can adjust the volume using:

```
MPMusicPlayerController *musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];
musicPlayer.volume = 1;
```

which will maximize the device volume in App.

Comment: thanks for your reply. so you mean that we can change the device volume .can we change the tunes through our app ?

Comment: yes, you can change the system tunes, you have to find the list of tunes and their ids, you can use those ids to change the tunes. some of them are here http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/AudioServices

Comment: No. You can't. http://stackoverflow.com/a/829380/188331